# Does all unary language belongs to P questions?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, computational-complexity

It's a simple and maybe silly question. Does all unary language aka belongs to {1*} a P language. It seems I can always check the input unary string in linear time to see if there exists one in the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. Take a [non recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_set) subset $S$ of $\Bbb{N}$. Then the language $\{1^n \mid n \in S\}$ will not even be decidable.